# For every language $L_1$, there exists a language $L_2$ such that $L_2$ is not mapping reducible to $L_1$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability

I've tried approaching this problem by contradiction, but that did not lead anywhere. Now I am attempting a proof by construction.

i.e. given a language $L_1$, construct a language $L_2$ that cannot be mapping reduced to $L_1$.

Comment: Please don't delete questions after you've received a good answer.  Part of our mission here is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful not only to you but also to others in the future.  Answerers may have responded on that basis, so it might be considered impolite to delete your question after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the set of all words is countable, and so is the set of all computable functions.

Suppose $\Sigma^* = \{x_1, x_2, …\}$ is the set of all words and $\mathcal{F} = \{f_1, f_2, …\}$ is the set of all computable functions.

For $L_1\subset \Sigma^*$, define $L_2 = \{x_i\in\Sigma^* \mid f_i(x_i)\notin L_1\}$. Then $L_2$ is not reducible to $L_1$.

Comment: But what if $L_1$ is neither the empty language, or the language of all words?

Comment: So the two statements you wrote clearly imply that $L_1$ cannot be empty, or all words. But $L_1$could still be a nonempty proper subset of all words.

Comment: Sorry, I switched the roles of $L_1$ and $L_2$. I edited my answer.